# Ошибка с recyclerView: setAdapter in RecyclerView cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android

Есть код

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    qrAdapter = new QRAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(qrAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
            false
    ));
}
```

При наведении на recyclerView.setAdapter(qrAdapter); высвечивается :

> setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)in
>   RecyclerView cannot be applied to
>   (com.example.ayapplication.QR.QRAdapter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, `com.example.ayapplication.QR.QRAdapter` не унаследован от `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter`